# Error running touchegg

Tags: elementary-os

I'm trying to run `touchegg` for the first time.  Error

```
me@pc:~$ touchegg
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(touchegg:22338): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(touchegg:22338): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(touchegg:22338): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(touchegg:22338): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Reading config from  "/home/bmackey/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf" 
Try to make a multitouch gesture. If everything goes well the information about the gesture must appear 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Flick 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Drag 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Pinch 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Rotate 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Tap 
[+] Avaliable gesture: 
     Name ->  Touch
```

I tried:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf`

and

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
   sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
  sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks`

Answer (score 0):

I  used [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) instead.  It works.  Sadly, with my particular trackpad I get PINCH detections when I swipe about 75% of the time.  As can be seen by running the command

```
### Test to print out commands that would be executed:
libinput-gestures -d
```

According to the [developer](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures/issues/28) it is an issue with `libinput` and there is nothing he can do about it.

I'll probably stick to using WINDOWS_KEY + ARROW.